# Can I use Gatsby to group my md files by tags on my blog

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I npm install the simple Gatsby demo.I want to set some tags to classify  my blog pages,and show on the index page. How can I set this?

Comment: To clarify. Do you want separate index pages per tag (e.g. /tag1/, /tag2/, /tag3/, etc.) or to just have one tag index page that shows all tags + their blog posts?